# How to resize images before uploading them in Flask?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, python-imaging-library

I have four images i want to upload them, but their sizes are very big it takes long time to upload them into the site.

I want to resize each one of them, i wrote a small route that handle the request:

```
@team_route.route('/team/dashboard/add/product', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@requires_auth
@master_login_required(role='master')
def team_add_product():
    form = AddProduct()
    imagesList = []
    size = 1024, 764
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_submitted():
        product = Goods()
        file = request.files.getlist("image[]")
        if file:
            for zipfile in file:
                fi = Image.open(BytesIO(zipfile.stream.read()))
                im.thumbnail(size)
                img2 = im.rotate(-90, expand=True)
                img2.seek(0)
                img2.save(UPLOAD_FOLDER + '/crops/' + zipfile)
```

When i hit upload it gives me this error:

`AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'`

Please any help solving this ?

Comment: Hello, have you tried to remove .stream? zipfile.read() its the only you need

Comment: Yea !! now it works , thanks dude :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `.stream`

`zipfile.read()` its the only you need.